# Terminate a thread when another thread starts

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, thread-safety

Basically, I have a long task that consists of bunch of sequence sub-tasks as follows:

```
class Task implements Runnable
{
    private Foo foo;

    public Task(Foo foo)
    {
        this.foo = foo;
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        doTask1(foo);
        doTask2(foo);
        doTask3(foo);
        doTask4(foo);
        // ...
        doTaskN(foo);
    }
}
```

What I need is to run only one instance of the `Task`, and if one `Task` begins, the other `Task`s (if any) should terminate immediately.

I used a single thread executor:

```
Executor executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
```

and I run the task as:

```
executor.execute(new Task(foo));
```

This guarantees that only one task executes at a time, but unfortunately it does not terminate the previous tasks.

---

However, I decide to use a boolean flag in between each 2 sub-tasks as follows:

```
class BooleanHolder
{
    boolean terminate = false;
}

class Task implements Runnable
{
    private Foo foo;
    private BooleanHolder bh;

    public Task(Foo foo, BooleanHolder bh)
    {
        this.foo = foo;
        this.bh = bh;
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        bh.terminate = false;
        doTask1(foo);
        if(bh.terminate) return;
        doTask2(foo);
        if(bh.terminate) return;
        doTask3(foo);
        if(bh.terminate) return;
        doTask4(foo);
        // ...
        if(bh.terminate) return;
        doTaskN(foo);
    }
}
```

and use it like this:

```
BooleanHolder bh = new BooleanHolder();

// ...

bh.terminate = true;
executor.execute(new Task(foo, bh));
```

However, this seems to be inefficient solution and not thread safe. Do you suggest a better solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the `ExecutorService` interface, instead of `Executor`, like this:

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
Future<?> future = executor.submit(new Task(foo));
```

You can then interrupt the running task in order to execute another task through the `cancel` method:

```
future.cancel(true);
```

As @RPT said however, you should structure your tasks in such a way to respond to interrupts, otherwise the interrupt signal will not have any effect. If your task has no operation which throws an `InterruptedException`, you should manually check the interrupt flag from time to time (similar to what you already did):

```
@Override
public void run()
{
    ....
    if (Thread.interrupted()) {
        // Release resources and end task
    }
    ....
}
```

By the way, this solves your problem, but does not actually terminate the thread inside ExecutorService.